# FunctionTransformer & creating new columns in pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, pipeline

I have a sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['X1', 'X2', 'X3'], data=[
                                               [1,16,9],
                                               [4,36,16],
                                               [1,16,9],
                                               [2,9,8],
                                               [3,36,15],
                                               [2,49,16],
                                               [4,25,14],
                                               [5,36,17]])
```

I want to create two complementary columns in my df based on x2 ad X3 and include it in the pipeline.

I am trying to follow the code:

```
def feat_comp(x):
 x1 = 100-x
 return x1

pipe_text = Pipeline([('col_test', FunctionTransformer(feat_comp, 'X2',validate=False))])
X = pipe_text.fit_transform(df)
```

It gives me an error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How can I apply the function transformer on selected columns and how can I use them in the pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add a new column based on a given column, e.g. `X2`.  You need to pass this column as an additional argument to the function using `kw_args`:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['X1', 'X2', 'X3'], data=[
                                               [1,16,9],
                                               [4,36,16],
                                               [1,16,9],
                                               [2,9,8],
                                               [3,36,15],
                                               [2,49,16],
                                               [4,25,14],
                                               [5,36,17]])

def feat_comp(x, column):
   x[f'100-{column}'] = 100 - x[column]
   return x

pipe_text = Pipeline([('col_test', FunctionTransformer(feat_comp, validate=False, kw_args={'column': 'X2'}))])
pipe_text.fit_transform(df)
```

Result:

```
   X1  X2  X3  100-X2
0   1  16   9      84
1   4  36  16      64
2   1  16   9      84
3   2   9   8      91
4   3  36  15      64
5   2  49  16      51
6   4  25  14      75
7   5  36  17      64
```

(in your example `FunctionTransformer(feat_comp, 'X2',validate=False)` `X2` would be the `inverse_func` and the string `X2` is not callalble, hence the error)

Comment: Thanks, You made it easy to understand

Comment: This is great. I've been trying to work out how to do this for ages, thanks! -1 for naming a column starting with a digit though :)

Comment: I recommend making a copy of `x` in the `feat_comp` function. Otherwise, the data frame is modified in-place in the function (i.e. no need for the return statement) and overwrite the dataframe.